# What is Oracle RefCursor type equavalent in System.Data.DbType enum in C#?

Tags: .net, oracle, enterprise-library

I'm programming a DataAccess code using Microsoft Enterprise Library, and I'm connecting to Oracle Database. When I try to call a Stored Procedure which expecting an out parameter of type RefCursor I can't pass it this type since the only available types are these types in "System.Data.DbType".
So which type should I pickup for Oracle "RefCursor" DbType?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a null placeholder: http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2007/08/27/enterprise-library-and-oracle-stored-procedure-record-sets/

You have to use a [parameter array list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748722%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx), you cannot use the AddParameter.

Comment: I have tried to get the stored procedure using:
`DbCommand command = oracleDB.GetStoredProcCommand("SP_NAME", null);`
But I got a "null reference" exception in this line!, the SP has only one parameter which the cursor ... it's of course output parameter!

Comment: @magdy.roshdy Yes, it doesn't work for parameterless SPs.  I don't think we've found a better workaround than just adding a dummy parameter which isn't used for anything.

Comment: Most of the details of this answer are hidden behind links and if the links die then this answer looses most of its worth. It would be better if you included the relevant parts of the solution in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I remembered, you can name your sys_refcursor "cur_OUT" in Oracle PLSQL side, and just use cmd.ExecutorReader() to retrieve the result on C# side, even without declare the cur_OUT parameter on Enterprise Library Data Access block side.

Here's doc (I forgot where the source is...):

**This means that you can name your reference cursor as "cur_OUT" and the Data Access Application Block will bind it for you; you do not need to explicitly create an output parameter for the cursor.** If your stored procedures use a cursor with a name other than "cur_OUT," you must explicitly add a parameter for each cursor to the command. Similarly, if your stored procedure contains multiple cursors, you must explicitly add each cursor parameter to the command.